# How add Bottom Modal Sheet within a Dialog Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

Opened by clicking a FAB, I have an `Add Item Dialog` which includes an option to assign an image to the shopping list item. Is it possible to implement a `Bottom Modal Sheet` with options for camera capture, etc. at the bottom of the `Dialog`?

Comment: What do you want with the `bottomsheetdialog?` it must be inside the dialog or default position? Its better if you tried it first

Comment: Inside the `bottomsheetdialog`, I want to have options for using the camera, gallery, or file system to assign the shopping list item an image. I tried this already but it was opening the sheet at the bottom of the activity screen rather than within the Dialog Composable. Unfortunately, I don't have my original implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ModalBottomSheetLayout` inside you're dialog, put you're bottom sheet composable inside the `sheetContent` part of this layout, and the rest of you're dialog in the `content` part of this layout, and then manipulate the open and closed state of the bottom sheet dialog with the `sheetState`

It will give you something like that :

```
// Create the sheet state
val mySheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)

// Add the layout
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        // You're camera caption button here, or anything else 
    },
    sheetState = mySheetState
) {
    // You're dialog content here
}

// Show or hide you're bottom sheet dialog
LaunchedEffect(Unit) { mySheetState.hide() }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) { mySheetState.show() }
```

Comment: This does not open the bottom sheet inside the dialog, it opens it inside the parent screen behind it. Please look at my other question with the implementation code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72491867/10259491